# Access VBA - updating specific field in a table

Tags: ms-access, vba

I want to update a specific field in table, with a criteria, from a table.
E.g. the user chooses an index of an item in the table simuhin1, and I want to update a field named "status" to 'Distributed'.
I already tried looking for it, but I couldn't find the code to look for the specific row I want.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should look up a beginner's tutorial in Microsoft Access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You try an update query.

```
UPDATE simuhin1 SET [status] = 'Distributed'WHERE [ID] = 'Number or Textbox Value'
```

Edit, you might need to slightly alter the number or textbox value formatting depending on where the number is being taken from.